# In a C# class project, what is AssemblyCulture used for?

Tags: c#, properties

Within a C# class project, there's the Properties file called AssemblyInfo.cs. Within this file are a series of assembly attributes including `AssemblyTitle`, `AssemblyDescription`, and so on, which are used to describe certain details about the compiled project. One of these is `AssemblyCulture`.

I understand what the others are used for, but **What is `AssemblyCulture` used to describe?** Language? Currency? A bit of both?

Whenever I've seen this property, it's been left blank.

Comment: [Assembly attributes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s.aspx)

Comment: @jlafay sorry about that - reading one property, typing another... Thanks for the fix

Comment: I have come across problems with having an `[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]` inside the AssemblyInfo.cs file. This causes Visual Studio Unit Test with this in the main project to fail. Commenting it out fixes the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199702/microsoft-unit-testing-failure-unable-to-load-dll-to-test

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute):

> The attribute is used by compilers to distinguish between a main assembly and a satellite assembly. A main assembly contains code and the neutral culture's resources. A satellite assembly contains only resources for a particular culture, as in `[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]`. Putting this attribute on an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code. Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it, because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points at runtime.

To summarize: This attribute is used internally by the framework to mark the *satellite assemblies* automatically created when you add localized resources to your project. You will probably never need to manually set this attribute to anything other than `""`.

Comment: MSDN is your friend. Well, most of the time it is.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute.aspx):

> The attribute is used by compilers to distinguish between a main
>   assembly and a satellite assembly. A main assembly contains code and
>   the neutral culture's resources. A satellite assembly contains only
>   resources for a particular culture, as in
>   `[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]`. Putting this attribute on
>   an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for
>   the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite
>   assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code.
>   Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it,
>   because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points
>   at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

When I googled your question I came up with a quick answer from <s>this tutorial</s>. It has a small description which I'm providing below and it looks like that's where you can specify localization but I'm not sure how much work it does for your assembly.

> AssemblyCultureAttribute Class implements AssemblyCulture attribute which is used to specify culture of an assembly as well as indicte that this is not a main assembly but rather its satellite.
>
> ```
> [assembly: AssemblyCulture("de")] // German
> ```

Comment: the link is broken