# .NET Assembly Culture

Tags: c#, .net

How do you change the assembly language in a C# application? There is a problem when we are using

```
[assembly:AssemblyCulture("en-US")]
```

There is an error:

**Error emitting'System.Reflection.AssemblyCultureAttribute' attribute -- 'Executables cannot be satellite assemblies, Culture should always be empty'**

Comment: I'd recommend changing the title to ".NET Assembly Culture", since assembly language (think x86 or ARM assembly) is completely different from any attribute in .NET.

Answer (score 13):

You should use

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

as the compiler suggests.

To define default culture, you should use

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Comment: ther is no change in language,stil language is "Language Neutral"

Comment: A .NET executable should look like this, showing "Language Neutral" in Properties dialog. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx

Comment: The previous link has been moved to a `.chm` file download. [May 2006 MSDN Magazine](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2006en-us.chm).

Comment: help me figure out What's the point in providing it, If it is intended to be kept empty.

Comment: @Hitsa00 when satellite assemblies are generated, that field is used for them to specify their culture. This field just needs to be kept blank for the main assembly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0):

> The attribute is used by compilers to distinguish between a main
> assembly and a satellite assembly. A main assembly contains code and
> the neutral culture's resources. A satellite assembly contains only
> resources for a particular culture, as in
> [assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]. Putting this attribute on
> an assembly and using something other than the empty string ("") for
> the culture name will make this assembly look like a satellite
> assembly, rather than a main assembly that contains executable code.
> Labeling a traditional code library with this attribute will break it,
> because no other code will be able to find the library's entry points
> at runtime.

To summarize: This attribute is used internally by the framework to mark the satellite assemblies automatically created when you add localized resources to your project. You will probably never need to manually set this attribute to anything other than "".

ref:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402206/in-a-c-sharp-class-project-what-is-assemblyculture-used-for](http://properties)