# VS2013 Express Unit Testing FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm starting a new solution which contains 6 projects, 2 class libraries, a website, and a unit testing project for each.

I am having trouble setting up the unit tests for one of the class libraries. This library uses entity framework and I would like to Mock the database context to test the various functions. The functions work when referenced from the website and other class library but not in the unit testing project.

When I try to run a unit test referencing that library, I get an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Now the error is pretty straight forward, it cannot find the class library's dll. The solution, however, is not so simple. I have spent a couple hours googling and trying different things. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. The DLL does exist in the location it says.
2. Changing the architecture of the tests to x64 or x86 does nothing, the class library is set to Any CPU
3. I tried changing all references on both the library and test project to copy local but that didn't help.
4. I have tried manually copying the dll and changing the reference point
5. The same library can be successfully called from the website project and the other class library
6. I have tried turning on the assembly bind logging but it didn't provide any new information

Currently the entire solution is bare bones so I am flexible on any suggestions. I am at my wits and googling end. Let me know if you would like more information.

Thank you for any help,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [Microsoft Unit Testing failure, unable to load DLL to test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199702/microsoft-unit-testing-failure-unable-to-load-dll-to-test?rq=1), if you set the AssemblyCulture to anything, the references won't work anymore. I figure this question/answer can stay up since I couldn't find the other one through  searching. I just got lucky to stumble upon it in the Related section.

Basically: Make sure, in AssemblyInfo.cs on both the unit test project and the project being tested that AssemblyCulture is an empty string:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Output was being written to (for example) bin/x86/Debug/Some.DLL but trying to load from bin/x86/Debug/en-US/Some.DLL.